# Unable to include .so files in ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have imported my project from `Eclipse` to `Android Studio` as I want to build my app for `Marshmallow` release. After migrating, I came to know that it doesn't support `.so` files directly from `libs` folder. To overcome it I looked few answers on stack overflow like

1) Creating `jniLibs` folder under `src\main`

2) Trying below in Gradle script :
`jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLibs/']`

3) creating `.jar` of `armeabi` folder and putting under `lib`(not `libs`) folder and then accessing it

But so far nothing worked. Can someone guide me what could be the issue?
Below is the **snapshot** of my project folder and **gradle.script** file

[image]

**gradle.script**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251' // write your encoding here

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLibs/']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe what is not working -- do you get an error, ...?

Comment: Yes, I get an error "could not find .so file"